# Greenbone/OpenVAS not starting tasks after reboot

Tags: security

I have Greenbone and OpenVAS installed on a Fedora machine. Configuration was OK and everything was working fine.

After a reboot every attempt to start a task results in the browser waiting forever for answer (with no effect: no task is started)

I nothing in the log files and `openvas-check-setup` shows no problems

```
$ openvas-check-setup
openvas-check-setup 2.3.3
  Test completeness and readiness of OpenVAS-8
  (add '--v6' or '--v7' or '--v9'
   if you want to check for another OpenVAS version)

  Please report us any non-detected problems and
  help us to improve this check routine:
  http://lists.wald.intevation.org/mailman/listinfo/openvas-discuss

  Send us the log-file (/tmp/openvas-check-setup.log) to help analyze the problem.

  Use the parameter --server to skip checks for client tools
  like GSD and OpenVAS-CLI.

Step 1: Checking OpenVAS Scanner ... 
        OK: OpenVAS Scanner is present in version 5.0.5.
        OK: OpenVAS Scanner CA Certificate is present as /etc/pki/openvas/CA/cacert.pem.
        OK: redis-server is present in version v=3.0.6.
        OK: scanner (kb_location setting) is configured properly using the redis-server socket: /tmp/redis.sock
        OK: redis-server is running and listening on socket: /tmp/redis.sock.
        OK: redis-server configuration is OK and redis-server is running.
        OK: NVT collection in /var/lib/openvas/plugins contains 47056 NVTs.
        WARNING: Signature checking of NVTs is not enabled in OpenVAS Scanner.
        SUGGEST: Enable signature checking (see http://www.openvas.org/trusted-nvts.html).
        OK: The NVT cache in /var/cache/openvas contains 47056 files for 47056 NVTs.
Step 2: Checking OpenVAS Manager ... 
        OK: OpenVAS Manager is present in version 6.0.8.
        OK: OpenVAS Manager client certificate is present as /etc/pki/openvas/CA/clientcert.pem.
        OK: OpenVAS Manager database found in /var/lib/openvas/mgr/tasks.db.
        OK: Access rights for the OpenVAS Manager database are correct.
        OK: sqlite3 found, extended checks of the OpenVAS Manager installation enabled.
        OK: OpenVAS Manager database is at revision 146.
        OK: OpenVAS Manager expects database at revision 146.
        OK: Database schema is up to date.
        OK: OpenVAS Manager database contains information about 47056 NVTs.
        OK: At least one user exists.
        OK: OpenVAS SCAP database found in /var/lib/openvas/scap-data/scap.db.
        OK: OpenVAS CERT database found in /var/lib/openvas/cert-data/cert.db.
        OK: xsltproc found.
Step 3: Checking user configuration ... 
        OK: The password policy file at /etc/openvas/pwpolicy.conf contains entries.
Step 4: Checking Greenbone Security Assistant (GSA) ... 
        OK: Greenbone Security Assistant is present in version 6.0.10.
Step 5: Checking OpenVAS CLI ... 
        OK: OpenVAS CLI version 1.4.4.
Step 6: Checking Greenbone Security Desktop (GSD) ... 
        SKIP: Skipping check for Greenbone Security Desktop.
Step 7: Checking if OpenVAS services are up and running ... 
        OK: netstat found, extended checks of the OpenVAS services enabled.
        OK: OpenVAS Scanner is running and listening on all interfaces.
        OK: OpenVAS Scanner is listening on port 9391, which is the default port.
        OK: OpenVAS Manager is running and listening on all interfaces.
        OK: OpenVAS Manager is listening on port 9390, which is the default port.
        OK: Greenbone Security Assistant is running and listening on all interfaces.
        OK: Greenbone Security Assistant is listening on port 9392, which is the default port.
Step 8: Checking nmap installation ...
        WARNING: Your version of nmap is not fully supported: 7.12
        SUGGEST: You should install nmap 5.51 if you plan to use the nmap NSE NVTs.
Step 10: Checking presence of optional tools ...
        OK: pdflatex found.
        OK: PDF generation successful. The PDF report format is likely to work.
        OK: ssh-keygen found, LSC credential generation for GNU/Linux targets is likely to work.
        OK: rpm found, LSC credential package generation for RPM based targets is likely to work.
        OK: alien found, LSC credential package generation for DEB based targets is likely to work.
        OK: nsis found, LSC credential package generation for Microsoft Windows targets is likely to work.
        OK: SELinux is disabled.

It seems like your OpenVAS-8 installation is OK.

If you think it is not OK, please report your observation
and help us to improve this check routine:
http://lists.wald.intevation.org/mailman/listinfo/openvas-discuss
Please attach the log-file (/tmp/openvas-check-setup.log) to help us analyze the problem.
```

How can I investigate the problem?

Comment: You need to do "openvas-start".